# Identity-like auto incrementing ID for groups of records

Tags: t-sql

I have a child table associated to the parent by the parent's primary key. Currently, the child table has a standard ID of `int IDENTITY(1,1)`. This is fine for my purposes and that will not change but to the user, they'll be seeing lists of disjointed IDs when they view the child rows associated to the parent.

**I would like to have a display ID that starts at 1 and increments (like an identity column) for each group of records.**

My child table would look something like this;

```
ChildID-PK ParentID-FK DisplayID
 1          1           1
 2          1           2
 3          2           1
 4          3           1
 5          1           3
```

Possible solutions;

- When inserting a record, `SELECT MAX(DisplayID) + 1 FROM tbl WHERE ParentID = @ParentID` to use as the new records DisplayID. I could see this being problematic if many people are editing a group of records at once.
- Use `ROW_NUMBER()` to get the DisplayID but, in this case, if a record were to be deleted the DisplayID for existing records could change. This can't happen because users may be referring to specific DisplayIDs when entering data.

Comment: If it's just for display purposes, can't you use a row_number() over order by ChildID clause when querying the records for a specific ParentID?

Comment: The issue there is that I don't want the display ID to change if a a row in the middle is deleted. The user could be referring to "child 4" but tomorrow when "child 3" is deleted, "child 4" becomes "child 3".

Comment: Even if you don't want to use `row_number()`, mellamokb's advice is basically right. You should **not** change a correct, reasonable implementation of a surrogate key only because of a presentation requirement (after all, surrogate keys should not be exposed anyway). If you really need a more natural key, create a new field in your table, and use some kind of SQL or server-side code to fill it.

Comment: I don't want to change the behavior of the key field. I only want to save a display ID for each child record, for the user **only**. I will not be referring to this ID in code.

Comment: It is far better to tell the users there will be gaps and that this is normal and expected. This is NOT a task you want to do if you can possibly avoid it and never do it without a requirement from the user that you have pushed back on and they still insist on. This is not a simple task and it is easy to get it wrong. It can be costly to develop and maintain and the user gains nothing 99% of the time.

Comment: @HLGEM: If all the proper locks are in place during the insert, what do you think can be an issue about `MAX(DisplayID)+1` other than a high transaction rate?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The safest way I can think of, is creating something similar to Oracle's sequence object. There is a good sample of doing so in this [Microsoft SQL Server Development Customer Advisory Team blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlcat/archive/2006/04/10/sql-server-sequence-number.aspx) (I prefer option 2).

You should create a sequence for every parent row inserted:

```
EXEC usp_CreateNewSeq N'ParentSeq' + @parentId
```

and get the next sequence for each row in your association table:

```
INSERT INTO [table] VALUES (@childId, @parentId, EXEC 'GetNewSeqVal_'+ @parentId)
```

I'm not sure about my syntax and I'm not able to check it know, so feel free to correct me.

---

**Simpler method:** add a column to parent table called `MaxChildId` with default value = 0. Each time you add a child row you should update this column and use its new value as the `DisplayID`.

```
declare @vid int

UPDATE [ParentTable]
SET @vid = MaxChildId+1, MaxChildId = MaxChildId+1
WHERE Id = ParentID
select @vid
```

This method could cause concurrences when updating parent table.

---

After all being said, I think you better consider a redesign for solving this problem.

Comment: Wouldn't the sequence table produce the same concurrency problems as maintaining a MaxChildId in the parent table or even selecting the MAX ChildID on insert?

Comment: @Orange Kid: inserting a row to a lightweight table and retrieving the [scope identity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) is a much lighter operation than updating a row in a table, because it require finding the row. Even the post writers said that "Option 2 improves concurrency significantly". Notice that this method performing the maintenance cleanup on the go.

Comment: Thanks. I think I'll give the first method a shot when I get some time.