# How to configure a table column in TSQL that works as a sequence depending on the values of another two columns?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table that looks like this:

```
ID  A   B   Count
-----------------
1  abc  0   1
2  abc  0   2
3  abc  1   1
4  xyz  1   1
5  xyz  1   2
6  xyz  1   3
7  abc  1   2
8  abc  0   3
```

The "Count" column is incremented by one in the next insertion depending on the value of fields "A" and "B". so for example, if the next record I want to insert is:

```
ID  A   B   Count
-----------------
   abc  0
```

The value of count will be 4.

I have been trying to find documentation about this, but I'm still quite lost in the MS SQL world! There must be a way to configure the "Count" column as a sequence dependent on the other two columns. My alternative would be to select all the records with A=abc and B=0, get the maximum "Count", and do +1 in the latest one, but I suspect there must be another way related to properly defining the Count column when creating the table.

Comment: _"My alternative would be to select all the records with A=abc and B=0, get the maximum "Count", and do +1 in the latest one"_ This is what I did when I needed this - in a pinch. However, the problem with this is that, by deleting rows, we can end up duplicating numbers from the sequence. A more reliable way to do this would be to maintain a sequence number in another table and always increment it. I don't know if there's any way to do this natively in SQL Server; afaik, the standard `identity` functionality only works across a whole table.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Identity-like auto incrementing ID for groups of records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030973/identity-like-auto-incrementing-id-for-groups-of-records) or [SQL - Identity Group By](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45693053/sql-identity-group-by) or etc.

Comment: what happens if you delete record with ID 2 and then add another with `abc`and `0`? The count of the new record will be 3 while there already is a record with count 3 for this combination. What should happen then ?

Answer (score 2):

The first question is: Why do you need this?

There is `ROW_NUMBER()` which will - provided the correct `PARTITION BY` in the `OVER()` clause - do this for you:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT,A VARCHAR(10),B INT);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
 (1,'abc',0)
,(2,'abc',0)
,(3,'abc',1)
,(4,'xyz',1)
,(5,'xyz',1)
,(6,'xyz',1)
,(7,'abc',1)
,(8,'abc',0);

SELECT *
      ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY A,B ORDER BY ID)
FROM @tbl
ORDER BY ID;
```

The problem is: **What happens if a row is changed or deleted?**

If you write this values into a persistant column and one row is removed physically, you'll have a gap. Okay, one can live with this... But if a value in `A` is changed from `abc` to `xyz` (same applies to `B` of course) the whole approach breaks.

If you still want to write this into a column you can use the `ROW_NUMBER()` from above to fill these values initially and a `TRIGGER` to set the next value with your `SELECT MAX()+1` approach for new rows.

If the set of combinations is limited you might [create a `SEQUENCE` (needs v2012+)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-sequence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) for each.

But - to be honest - the whole issue smells a bit.

Comment: Haha :) Thanks a lot for this. Yes, I agree the whole issue smells, it's the result of a long story at work where the people who asked us for this "feature" won. We shouldn't need the count number at all in the DB, since it's redundant, but :shrug:.