# How can I automatically update all other rows in the table after insert one new one in sql?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this where I keep a list of appointments which increment based on the combination of A and B:

```
ID  A   B  Appointment  Count
-----------------------------
1  abc  0  2010-10-20   1
2  abc  0  2010-10-25   2
3  abc  0  2010-10-30   3
3  abc  1  2010-10-30   1
4  xyz  1  2010-08-18   1
5  xyz  1  2010-08-19   2
6  xyz  1  2010-08-20   3
```

And a function like this:

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GenerateCount
(
   @id int,
   @A int,
   @B int,
   @appt_date date

)
RETURNS Int
AS
BEGIN

   RETURN
   (
       SELECT COUNT(*)
       FROM dbo.test_seq
       WHERE patient_id = @A
       AND B = @B
       AND id <= @id
       AND appt_date <= @appt_date
   )
END
```

With data inserted like this:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test_seq](
    [id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [A] [int] NOT NULL,
    [B] [int] NOT NULL,
    [appt_date] [date] NOT NULL,
    [count] AS dbo.GenerateCount(id, A, B, appt_date)
    )
```

When I insert a new entry in the table, it increments the count as expected. However if I insert a new entry with a date in the middle, say if I want to add:

```
ID  A   B  Appointment  Count
-----------------------------
1  abc  0  2010-10-21
```

it has the correct count assigned, but the other rows don't get updated. How can I trigger a table update for all the other records after that date so they are corrected with the relevant count values?

I tried creating a trigger on insert/update/delete, but that only applies to the row being inserted and not the whole table.

Comment: As the answers already provided are strongly hinting - don't *store* that which can be *calculated*. As you're already finding out, all you're really doing by storing the result is *introducing* the opportunity for the stored value to be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I get this correctly, the simple answer is: Don't!

A SQL-Server-table is not Excel...

You must decide

- Do you want to set a value **persistantly** (in other words: a kind of *key*)?
- Do you just want to number the rows for the moment?

Create a `VIEW` upon your table (according to the approach [you find in your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49896884/5089204)).

This will compute the correct numbers whenever you call that.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just create a view

```
SELECT seq.* 
     , row_number() over (partition by A, B order by Appointment, ID) as [count]
FROM dbo.test_seq seq
```

Why the `AND id <= @id`?  That is just going to break stuff if you do insert a date in the middle.